# How to store array's values in lowercase?

Tags: excel, vba

I read data I stored in a worksheet table into a VBA array. I need the first "column" of this array to be in lowercase. (The purpose of this array is to allow quicker calculations with the data contained in the table without referring to the table itself.)
I do this with the "LCase()" function, and I used the "Debug.print()" function to verify that they are being stored as lowercase.
However, later on in the code when I refer to this array, the values have reverted to their original case. I haven't added/edited the array beyond the point that I read the table data into it.

Simplified code:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim tbl_Data as ListObject
Dim arr(1 to 10, 1 to 2) as Variant
Dim i as Integer
Dim calcValue as Single
Dim stringMatch as String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
Set tbl_Data = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

For i = 1 to tbl_Data.ListRows.Count
    arr(i, 1) = LCase(tbl_Data.DataBodyRange(i, 1))
    arr(i, 2) = tbl_Data.DataBodyRange(i, 2))
    Debug.Print(arr(i, 1)) 'Returns lowercase values normally
Next i

'---Insert calculations here
'- Returns calcValue (ex. calcValue = 10.12)

For i = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)
    If calcValue = arr(i, 2) Then
        Debug.Print(arr(i, 1)) 'Returns strings with original case values
        stringMatch = arr(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

I do not see an issue with the code that would cause the values stored to revert back to the original.

The original code. I hope that it makes sense, without the context of the data itself.

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateInventory()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh_NewInventory As Worksheet
Dim sh_MasterInventory As Worksheet
    
Dim tbl_MasterInventory As ListObject
    
Dim cell_NewIngredient As Range
    
Dim arr_NewIngredients(1 To 30, 1 To 4) As Variant
Dim arr_MasterInventory(1 To 60, 1 To 6) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
Dim bool_isCellBlank As Boolean
Dim bool_isIngredientMatch As Boolean

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh_NewInventory = wb.Worksheets("Update Inventory")
Set sh_MasterInventory = wb.Worksheets("Food Inventory")

Set tbl_MasterInventory = sh_MasterInventory.ListObjects("MasterInventory")
    
Set cell_NewIngredient = sh_NewInventory.Range("B3")

bool_isCellBlank = False
bool_isIngredientMatch = False

i = 1
Do While Not bool_isCellBlank
    arr_NewIngredients(i, 1) = LCase(cell_NewIngredient)
    arr_NewIngredients(i, 2) = LCase(cell_NewIngredient.Offset(0, 1))
    arr_NewIngredients(i, 3) = cell_NewIngredient.Offset(0, 2)
    arr_NewIngredients(i, 4) = cell_NewIngredient.Offset(0, 3)
    i = i + 1
    Set cell_NewIngredient = cell_NewIngredient.Offset(1, 0)
    bool_isCellBlank = (cell_NewIngredient = "")
Loop
    
For i = 1 To tbl_MasterInventory.ListRows.Count
    arr_MasterInventory(i, 1) = LCase(tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, 1))
    arr_MasterInventory(i, 2) = LCase(tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, 2))
    For j = 1 To tbl_MasterInventory.ListColumns.Count - 2
        arr_MasterInventory(i, j) = tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(arr_NewIngredients, 1)
    j = 0
    bool_isIngredientMatch = False
    Do While Not bool_isIngredientMatch
        j = j + 1
        If arr_NewIngredients(i, 1) = LCase(arr_MasterInventory(j, 1)) Then
            bool_isIngredientMatch = True
            Debug.Print (arr_NewIngredients(i, 1) & " : " & arr_MasterInventory(j, 1))
        End If
    Loop
Next i

End Sub
```

RESULTS: Immediate Window
[image]

Comment: I run your script and have no problem with lowercase. Maybe the problem is in the calculations part that you did not send.

Comment: Suspect you have over-simplified your problem.  If you run the code you posted what do you see?

Comment: Alright, check out the updated question. I've included my original code and a copy of my results!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

See the following code (reading data into the array):

```
For i = 1 To tbl_MasterInventory.ListRows.Count
    arr_MasterInventory(i, 1) = LCase(tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, 1))
    arr_MasterInventory(i, 2) = LCase(tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, 2))
    For j = 1 To tbl_MasterInventory.ListColumns.Count - 2
        arr_MasterInventory(i, j) = tbl_MasterInventory.DataBodyRange(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

I made a mistake in the loop using the "j" index. By starting at "j=1", I was replacing what I had done prior to the "j" For loop, which was what caused the data to be re-entered as the original version.

I feel real dumb for making the mistake, but I'm glad y'all looked at it for me! Thanks again!